# Extendability of $L^{p}$ harmonic functions

Tags: reference-request, elliptic-pde, harmonic-functions

Let $u$ be a harmonic function on some open set $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $u\in L^{p}\left(\Omega\right)$. Is there any reference on extending $u$ to harmonic function on a larger open set $\Omega'$ and to be from $L^{p}\left(\Omega'\right)$?

Comment: What about $\log r$ on $R^2\setminus\{0\}$?

Comment: In general, a harmonic function in any $L^p$, even with $p=\infty$ does not extend to a larger open set.

Comment: Where can I find that? I need only the case $1\leq p<\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

For every $n$ and for every regular region (in the sense of Dirichlet problem), it is easy to construct a harmonic function
in $L^\infty$ that does not extend to any larger open set. Just solve the Dirichlet
problem with a continuous nowhere differentiable boundary data.

If the boundary has irregular points, for example an isolated point, such extension is
sometimes possible, depending on $n$ and $p$. One can make an exact statement about $n$ and $p$ for this kind of "removable singularity theorem", if this is what you really want.
For example, if $p=\infty$, closed sets of zero capacity are removable, but closed sets
of positive capacity are not.